# How to get a parent div to float/break into an L/wrap between children?

Tags: css, css-float

I thought I understood float, but clearly I don't.

I have a div (class="Sophia") made of a header ("h2"), and an unordered list ("ul") containing images that I want to collapse into an L-formation. Specifically I want the header (containg the text "sophia") to go into the gap that is under "Dorothy" and to the left of "Rose."

I realize that I could accomplish this by breaking the header out of the div, but for the sake of learning I want to know how to use CSS to style the div as a whole unit such that it "breaks" between elements into an L, such that the upper part of the L goes into empty space, just with CSS.

### How things are now:

[image]

### Kind of what the goal is:

[image: Goal]

If you know how to pull this off, I'd love it if you could show me how!

Thanks!

This is the codepen: http://codepen.io/ihatecoding/pen/WpBZpy

This is the snippet:

```css
/* body formatting, not important */
body {font-family:"Gudea";
background-color: lightGray;
padding: 15px;}

.sophiaword{color:darkblue;}
h1 {text-align:center;}

a {text-decoration:none;
color:darkblue;}

.wrapper{
  padding: 10px 25%;
  width:50%;  
}

/*this is the formatting that matters*/

.dorothy,
.rose,
.sophia {
float:left;

}

.dorothy, 
.rose {
width:50%;
}


.sophia { 
width:auto;
}

.dorothy li {
 width:100%;
 }

.rose li {
width:47%;
}

.sophia li {
width:20%;
display:block;
float:left;

}

.dorothy h2,
.rose h2,
.sophia h2{
color:black;
font-size: 40px;
  margin:0;
}

li  {
background-color: #f7f7f7;
margin:0 1% !important;
padding:0 !important;
    width: 22%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cat-post-item span,
.cat-post-item a {
  color: darkSlateGray;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.cat-post-item img {
    margin: 0 !important;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.cat-post-thumbnail span, 
.cat-post-thumbnail img {
width:100% !important; 
}

.sophia li {
width:20%;
display:block;
float:left;

}
```

```html
<span><h1>I'd like to know how to use CSS and float to get the blue text "<span class="sophiaword">Sophia</span>" to flow so it breaks away from the row of sophia images, and ends up next to the left of the the bottom picture of rose. In the end I'd like the "sophia" div to make an "L"-shape, but stay as one div. Currently the div starts on a new line and I don't want that. </h1></span>

<div class="wrapper">

<div class="   dorothy">
  <h2>
  <a href="http://www.example.com">Dorothy</a>
  </h2>
  <ul>

    <li class='cat-post-item'>
    <a class="cat-post-thumbnail" href="http://www.example.com" >
      <span>
        <img width="150" height="150" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Buhe7x1CAAAIW02.jpg" class="attachment-150x150 size-150x150 wp-post-image" />
      </span>
    </a>
    <a class="cat-post-title" href="http://www.example.com" >Dorothy (down there ↓)</a> 
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="rose">
  <h2 >
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Rose</a>
  </h2><ul >

  <li class='cat-post-item'>
  <a class="cat-post-thumbnail" href="http://www.example.com" >
    <span><img width="150" height="148" src="http://www.dvdizzy.com/images/g-i/ggs2-12.jpg" class="attachment-150x150 size-150x150 wp-post-image"  />
    </span>
  </a>
  <a  href="http://www.example.com" >Rose1</a> 
  </li>
  
  <li class='cat-post-item'>
    <a class="cat-post-thumbnail" href="http://www.example.com" >
      <span>
        <img width="150" height="112" src="http://www.dvdizzy.com/images/g-i/ggs2-12.jpg" class="attachment-150x150 size-150x150 wp-post-image"  />
      </span>
    </a>
    <a  href="http://www.example.com" >Rose2</a> 
  </li>
  
  <li class='cat-post-item'>
    <a class="cat-post-thumbnail" href="http://www.example.com" >
      <span>
        <img width="147" height="150" src="http://www.dvdizzy.com/images/g-i/ggs2-12.jpg" class="attachment-150x150 size-150x150 wp-post-image"  />
      </span>
    </a>
    <a  href="http://www.example.com" > ( ← over there ) Rose3 </a> 
  </li>
  
  <li class='cat-post-item'>
    <a class="cat-post-thumbnail" href="http://www.example.com" >
      <span>
        <img width="92" height="150" src="http://www.dvdizzy.com/images/g-i/ggs2-12.jpg" class="attachment-150x150 size-150x150 wp-post-image"  />
      </span>
    </a>
    <a  href="http://www.example.com" >Rose4 </a> 
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="  sophia">

  <h2 class="widget-title">
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Sophia</a>
  </h2>

  <ul >

    <li class='cat-post-item'>
      <a class="cat-post-thumbnail" href="http://www.example.com" >
        <span>
          <img width="150" height="101" src="http://underscoopfire.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/sophia-petrillo.jpg" class="attachment-150x150 size-150x150 wp-post-image"  />
        </span>
      </a>
      <a  href="http://www.example.com" >Sophia1</a> 
    </li>
    
    <li class='cat-post-item'>
      <a class="cat-post-thumbnail" href="http://www.example.com" >
        <span>
          <img width="150" height="101" src="http://underscoopfire.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/sophia-petrillo.jpg" class="attachment-150x150 size-150x150 wp-post-image"  />
        </span>
      </a>
      <a  href="http://www.example.com" >Sophia2</a> </li><li class='cat-post-item'>
    <a class="cat-post-thumbnail" href="http://www.example.com" >
    <span> <img width="150" height="101" src="http://underscoopfire.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/sophia-petrillo.jpg" class="attachment-150x150 size-150x150 wp-post-image"  />
    </span>
    </a>
    <a  href="http://www.example.com" >Sophia3</a> 
    </li>
   
    <li class='cat-post-item'><a class="cat-post-thumbnail" href="http://www.example.com" >
    <span>
      <img width="150" height="101" src="http://underscoopfire.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/sophia-petrillo.jpg" class="attachment-150x150 size-150x150 wp-post-image"  />
    </span>
    </a>
    <a  href="http://www.example.com" >Sophia4</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you make something even in like mspaint or something to show what you're meaning by "L" shape

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I added the image to the question, reload it to see the image.